# mount fsx in Dockerfile is throwing returned a non-zero code: 22

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile, mount, amazon-fsx

I am trying to mount fsx in the Dockerfile with following command:

```
RUN mount -t lustre file_system_dns_name@tcp:/mountname /mnt/fsx -o noatime,flock
```

But it throws following error:

```
INFO:batscli.process.process_runner:stdout> {"event": "Docker image build failed, please check log output", "exc_info": true, "exception": {"args": ["The command '/bin/sh -c mount -t lustre file_system_dns_name@tcp:/mountname /mnt/fsx -o noatime,flock' returned a non-zero code: 22"], .....
```

I cannot write the mount command in separate bash file, because I need it in BATS_TRANSFORM package, which only copies Dockerfile, and not other shell scripts.

Comment: You can't run `mount` in a Docker container at all, unless you give the container unusual privileges.  You can't give the build sequence those privileges, and therefore you can't run `mount` in a Dockerfile ever.  (In any case, the built image wouldn't persist the mount.)

Comment: I know people have done it in the docker. But they do it by adding above line in a shell script and calling it from dockerfile. The only problem here is that I need it build it with BATS_TRANSFORM package, which only copies Dockerfile, and not other shell scripts. So i guess my struggle is why mount command works if we write in separate shell scipt, but not when it is added in Dockerfile. I guess it has to do something with formatting.

Comment: did you found answer?

Comment: It has to do with the the version of AL2 AMI. Change it to older version of the AMI, and should work.